# Shiny App - Data Table Displays when Running Locally but not When Published

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, shiny

I built a Shiny app that relies on loading a locally stored CSV file upon startup. When I run the Shiny app on my computer, whether in an RStudio window or Google Chrome, the app loads and displays the data without a problem. This is the case even without the data loaded into the R session. After publishing the app, however, the main data table does not display on startup or after hitting the submit button (in an attempt to refresh the table).

This issue began when I switched from using Shiny's data table function to using DT's. I began using DT in order to be able to enable the names in the first column to serve as links. I'm currently working on a 64 bit Macbook running Mavericks. Just updated R and RStudio today while troubleshooting. I've tried publishing from a computer running Windows 8 as well - data table still does not display in the published version of the app.

ui.r code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Pinball Buyer's Guide"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("Whether you're looking for a great value on a machine to buy or just want to find a new table you'd
                     like to play, this guide will help you find a table based on your tastes. Use the sliders below to
                     assign a weight to each category of your table ranking score. The site will use that to generate
                     a score for each of the available tables and to determine how much bang for your buck each table
                     represents."),

            sliderInput('rating',
                    label = 'Player Ratings',
                    value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),

            sliderInput('game',
                    label = 'Game Design',
                    value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),

            sliderInput('art',
                         label = 'Art',
                        value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),


            sliderInput('sound',
                    label = 'Sound',
                    value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),

            sliderInput('other',
                         label = 'Other Game Aspects',
                        value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),

            sliderInput('staff',
                         label = 'Pinside Staff Ratings',
                        value = 1, min = 0, max = 5, step = .25),

            helpText("Excluding the production year in the pricing model will likely push older tables
                     to the top of the bargain rankings. If you'd prefer a newer machine, leave this checked."
                ),

            checkboxInput('year',
                         label = 'Include Machine Year in Price Model?',
                         value = TRUE),

            submitButton('Submit')

            ),


        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Main",
                    br(),
                    textOutput('topTableExplainer'),
                    br(),
                    dataTableOutput('topTables'),
                    br()

                ),
                tabPanel("About This App", 
                         tags$body(textOutput('summary')),
                         br()
                )
            )
        )
    )
))
```

---

server.r code:

```
library(DT)
pinData <- read.csv('./Data/pinDataMassaged.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

userTable <- data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output){

    getUserFrame <- reactive({
        userScore <- pinData$rating * input$rating + pinData$gameDesign * input$game + pinData$artwork * input$art +
            pinData$sound * input$sound + pinData$otherRating  * input$other + pinData$staffRating * input$staff

        userTable <- data.frame()
        userTable <- data.frame(pinData, userScore)

        if (input$year == 'TRUE'){
                userModel <- lm(avgValue ~ userScore + age, data = userTable)
        }   else{
                userModel <- lm(avgValue ~ userScore, data = userTable)
        }

        pricePredict <- predict(userModel, userTable)

        pinBargain <- round(pricePredict - userTable$avgValue)

        userTable <- data.frame(userTable, pinBargain)

        userTable <- userTable[,c('nameLink', 'makeAndYear', 'userScore', 'estimatedValue', 'pinBargain')]
    })

    output$topTables <- DT::renderDataTable({

        DT::datatable(data = getUserFrame(),
                    colnames = c('Name', 'Make & Year', 'Your Score', 'Market Price', 'Bargain Amount($)'), 
                    escape = 0, rownames = FALSE, 
                    options = list(pageLength = 20, order = list(2,'desc')))
    })



    output$topTableExplainer <- renderText({
        "The following table presents the top-scoring games based on your criteria. The Bargain Amount column is how much
        of a value buy this game represents when compared to a pricing model based on your criteria. The higher the better. 
        Negative numbers represent games that are overpriced according to the pricing model. 
        Click on the Bargain Amount column to sort by best value. These tables would
        be a great, low-cost way to start your collection."
    })


    output$summary <- renderText({
        "   This app was born after I read way too many 'What should I buy?' discussions on pinball forums. I figured that people
        would appreciate the ability to find great tables based on what they consider most important in a game. As someone longing
        to buy his first pinball machine, I also knew that people would be looking for value tables that they could get a lot of
        game time out of. The data comes from the Pinside top ~250 tables. Some had to be excluded because pricing information
        wasn't available."
    })    

}
)
```

---

I don't get any error or warning messages when I publish the app, and there are no logs in the application log section of Shiny. Not sure where to turn. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I needed to change the dataTableOutput in ui.r to DT::dataTableOutput. Having it run correctly in R and in a local browser really threw me off and had me thinking it was a data load issue when it was the display/output that was wrong. MLavoie, thanks for cleaning up the code upon submit.